# Correct polarity in a circuit

Tags: dc, symbol, polarity

I am new to electronics and i am having trouble finding how to properly connect a DC circuit to a power suply. I don't understand the ***symbology*** used.

Do i have to connect the positive (+) terminal of the power suply to the positive (+) terminal marked on my circuit board or to the negative (-)  terminal?

Each time i see a component wich has polarity (such as diodes or capacitors), the marking of the component (+) goes to the (+) terminal on the power suply, or to the (-) terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect the positive terminal of the battery or power supply to the positive terminal of the circuit.

For components, the positive terminal is generally connected to the "more positive" point in the circuit, which may not be directly connected to the positive power supply.